# Mongoose returns empty array while mongodb terminal returns the required results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

A query gave me the required result in MongoDB while it's returning an empty array in mongoose

```
db.users.aggregate([

{$match:{_id:ObjectId("5d5a8b83352b262670a4d47b")}},
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "userclaims",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "userId",
         as: "claims"
       }},{
       $unwind:"$claims"
       }
])
```

this query, when executed in mongodb terminal, yielded the right result

```
User.aggregate([
        {$match:{_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5d5a8b83352b262670a4d47b")}},
        {
            $lookup:{
                from:"UserClaim",
                localField:"_id",
                foreignField:"userId",
                as:"claims"
            }
        },{
            $unwind:"$claims"
        }
    ])
    .exec().then((claims)=>{
        console.log(claims)
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
```

this is the code that I've written in mongoose which is logging `[]`.

Comment: Can you just pass mongoose.ObjectId instead of mongoose .Types.ObjectId?

Comment: @SunnyParekh it's throwing an error asking me to user mongoose.Types.ObjectId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using mongo collection name(userclaims) instead of mongoose model in $lookup from

Comment: It's a good culture to upvote an answer if it helped.

Comment: I couldn't..as I've no required reputation :(